# " 'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path " error in micropost model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

When I attempt to view the user profile page, I get the error above.

Here's my show.html.erb code:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>

<div class="row">

  <aside class="span4">
    <section>
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
    </section>
  </aside>

  <div class="span8">
    <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
      <h3>Microposts (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
      <ol class="microposts">
        <%= render @microposts %>
      </ol>
      <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

</div>
```

where `<%= render @microposts %>` is causing the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you declare the variable `@microposts` anywhere? At a glance, looks like what you should be doing is

```
<%= render @user.microposts %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue

yes, the `@microposts` is declared in the controller show method as:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

Update: I've found that the show action is defined twice (one of them defines `@microposts`). To solve this issue, I simply removed the second `show` action which doesn't define `@microposts`. I wonder how more than one person could have managed to duplicate the show action.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when I was passing a nested block to a render partial call like so:

```
// _content_header.haml
.content-header
  %h1= title
  = yield if block_given?

// edit.html.haml
= render partial: 'shared/content_header', locals: { title: 'Editing Movie' } do
  = link_to 'Show'
```

Calling `render` without the `partial` and `locals` keyword fixed it for me:

```
= render 'shared/content_header', title: 'Editing Movie' do
  = link_to 'Show'
```